# need scalable, highly available transactional log server

Tags: logging, failover, high-availability, redundancy

My requirements:

1) must be able to continue operating after node failure
2) logs must be recoverable after node failure - no data loss
3) must be able to scale out
4) must be transactional - when a message is logged, I need a guarantee that it is persisted to disk

This is similar to a previous question of mine, but I just realized that importance of the transactional feature. This is for a medical app; we cannot afford to lose any log messages.

Thanks!!

Comment: Persistence guaranties means that if log server is crashed - main application will not be able to finish its procedure. Is logging really that important that everything stops working if logs fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reliable forwarding with rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_reliable_forwarding.html) will get you started.  The [rsyslog docs](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/manual.html) also have pages describing how to write the data to a database and how to scale writing to a database.

Now this setup does not specifically handle automatic fail-over between multiple log servers. I personally didn't worry about it as each client sending logging data would queue the data on their end until the logging server was back up. And I had monitors in place that would notify me of the logging server being down.

IF you already had a DB system that had appropriate fail-over and high-availability setup, you could setup two logging servers and use a heartbeat system (perhaps [linux-ha](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page)) to do automatic take-over of the IP from the live logging server.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Sadly, these are windows servers, so I can't run rsyslog client on them. Otherwise, this would be a nice solution.
I am thinking of using flume (http://github.com/cloudera/flume) if I can build it for windows.

Answer (score 0):

From what you described above what you want is continuous-computing. There are 2 sort of software on windows based platform that can provide what you are looking for. I'm not too familiar with any transactional log applications. With both the below HA/FT solutions, you could just use about any out there. ( just as long they run in windows )

1. [Neverfail](http://www.neverfailgroup.com/)

Neverfail is a HA solution that protects your application from any data loss. In an event of a server outage, failover between both servers are seemless ( does not require human interaction) and depending on how much data is still left in the memory that isn't written to I/O on the Active server, the Passive Server will take over operations. This would provide you with close to 99.99% uptime.

2. [Marathon](http://www.marathontechnologies.com)

Marathon is similar like Neverfail but it has an added protection which is component protection. With their FT feature, if any failure were to happen to your sever, like a disk failure or even a network failure, your application will keep on running. Thus no data loss or interruption to business.